# Angular velocity in body-frame vs inertial frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

This question is based on the nomenclature and definitions in *Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics*.

In [Section 2.2](https://tgvaughan.github.io/sicm/chapter002.html#h1-8), we start with a rotation $\mathscr{M}(q(t))$ where $q$ is the path describing the motion of the body. The rotation is later represented by the rotation matrix $\mathbf{M}$.

To paraphrase:

> Let $\vec{\xi}_\alpha(t)$ be the vector to some constituent particle with the body in the orientation specified by q(t) given by $q(t)$, and $\vec{\xi'}_\alpha$ be the vector to the same constituent with the body in the reference orientation, then:

> $$
> \vec{\xi}_\alpha(t) = \mathscr{M}(q(t)) \vec{\xi'}_\alpha\tag{2.11}
> $$

Through a series of steps, it shows how the angular velocity vector consists of the components that can be extracted from the skew-symmetric matrix $D\mathbf{M} \mathbf{M}^\intercal$. Or

$$
\mathbf{\omega} = \mathscr{A}^{-1}( D\mathbf{M} \mathbf{M}^\intercal )
$$

$\mathscr{A}^{-1}$ is defined as the function that can extract the components of the angular velocity vector from an anti-symmetric matrix. In Eq. 2.20, it defines the derivative of the position of any constituent particle in the rigid body as:

$$
\dot{\vec{\xi}}_\alpha = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{\xi}_\alpha\tag{2.20}
$$

While it is not explicitly mentioned anywhere, I assume that the angular velocity components mentioned above are in terms of the inertial reference frame. So after this, it goes on to state the following:

> The components $\omega'$ of the angular velocity vector on the body axes are $\omega'= \mathbf{M}^\intercal \omega$, so

> $$
> \mathbf{\omega}' =\mathbf{M}^\intercal \mathscr{A}^{-1}( D\mathbf{M} \mathbf{M}^\intercal )\tag{2.21}
> $$

So here is my question:

In Eq. 2.11, $\mathbf{M}_\alpha$ seems to transform $\vec{\xi}$ from its reference frame components $\vec{\xi}'$ to its body-fixed frame components at time $t$. But in the last equation, angular velocity is transformed from reference to body-frame components as $\omega'= \mathbf{M}^\intercal \omega$. Why is it $\mathbf{M}^\intercal$ for angular velocity and not $\mathbf{M}$?

Is this somehow inferred from the prior steps?

Comment: skew-symmetric matrix of the angular velocity $\mathbf{\dot{M}} \mathbf{M}^\intercal$ . Matrix components of the angular velocity are given in inertial system. The transformation matrix transformed the vector components of from body to internal system.

Answer (score 0):

The angular velocity skew matrix  is:

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\ 
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]_I=
\mathbf{\dot{M}}\,\mathbf{M}^T\tag 1$$

where $~\mathbf M~$ is the transformation matrix between body system (B-system) and inertial system (I-system)

from equation (1) you obtain the components of the angular velocity vector in inertial system$~(\vec\omega)_I~$ , the components of the angular velocity vector in B-system
are
$$(\vec\omega)_B=\mathbf M^T\,(\vec\omega)_I$$

---

the components of the angular velocity vector in B-system  can also obtained  with this equation

\begin{align*} \mathbf M^T\,&\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\ 
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]_I\,\mathbf M=
\mathbf M^T\,\mathbf{\dot{M}}\,\mathbf{M}^T\,\mathbf M\quad \Rightarrow\\\\
 &\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\ \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\ 
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]_B=
\mathbf M^T\,\mathbf{\dot{M}}\end{align*}

Comment: How did you get $\mathbf{M}^T$ <matrix> $\mathbf{M}$ ? Why is it not the other way around ($M$ <matrix> $M^T$) ?

Comment: Which equation?

Comment: In your comment: " the components of the angular velocity vector in B-system are ...", how was that derived? Why is it $\mathbf{M}^T$ and not $\mathbf{M}$ that is used to transform $\omega_I$?

And similarly, when transforming the skew-symmetric matrix, why do you left multiply by $\mathbf{M}^T$ and right-multiply by $\mathbf{M}$ instead of the opposite?

Comment: \begin{align*}
 &{_B^I}\mathbf{M}\quad,\text{ M is the transformation matrix  from B-Frame to I-Frame and}\\
 &{_I^B}\mathbf{M}=\mathbf M^T\,\quad,\text{ $~M^T~$  is the transformation matrix  from I-Frame to B-Frame where}\\
 &{_B^I}\mathbf{M}\,{_I^B}\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{I}
\end{align*}
 thus vector transformation
 \begin{align*}
 &{_B^I}\mathbf{M} \vec{v}_B=\vec{v}_I\\
 &{_I^B}\mathbf{M}\,\vec{v}_I=\vec{v}_B
 \end{align*}

Comment: Matrix transformation  
 \begin{align*}
   &{_I^B}\mathbf{M}\, \mathbf A_I\,{_B^I}\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{A}_B\quad,
   \mathbf M^T\,\mathbf A_I\,\mathbf M=\mathbf A_B\\
   & {_B^I}\mathbf{M}\, \mathbf A_B\,{_I^B}\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{A}_I\quad,
\mathbf M\,\mathbf A_B\,\mathbf M^T=\mathbf A_I
 \end{align*}

Comment: Why is it that when transforming the position vector from inertial ($\vec{\xi'}_\alpha$) to body-frame $\vec{\xi}_\alpha$, $\mathbf{M}$ was used (Eq. 2.11 in the book)? 

This is the source of my confusion. The transformation is the same in both cases: inertial -> body. But for the position vector, they use $\mathbf{M}$, and for the angular velocity vector, they use $\mathbf{M}^\intercal$.

Comment: $~\vec{\xi'}~$ is in  B-Frame and $~\vec{\omega}~$ is in I-Frame right ?

Comment: Right after Eq 2.11: "The constituent vectors $\vec{\xi'}_\alpha$ do not depend on the configuration, because they are the vectors to the positions of the constituents with the body in a fixed reference orientation".

And prior to that: "Let $\vec{\xi}_\alpha(t)$ be the vector to some constituent particle with the body in the orientation specified by $q(t)$, and let $\vec{\xi'}_\alpha$ be the vector to the same constituent with the body in the reference orientation".

That makes it seem like $\vec{\xi'}_\alpha$ is the inertial vector, right?

Comment: and  $~\vec\omega'~$ is in B-system , this doesn't make sense